# Xcode doesn't find assets which have been imported before

Tags: ios, xcode, avaudioplayer, assets, audio-player

I try to play music with the AVAudioPlayer of the AVFoundation.
The line triggering the player is this one:

```
playBackgroundMusic("background-music-aac")
```

I previously imported the file (.caf) as you can see here:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/UJ3Fr.jpg

Still Xcode can't find it, as you also can see in the image.

Answer (score 0):

When you select the audio file `background-music-aac` make sure that it will be compiled with your target. Please check if it is selected on your File Inspector on the right hand panel of Xcode.